# Fill Header and Footer on iPhone X

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, iphone-x

I have a problem while doing a header and footer programmatically on a collection view in Swift 4. Here is an image of my app on an iPhone X:

[image: Click here to see the image.]

I want to extend the header till the very top of the screen (in the notch area) and the footer till the actual end of the screen. How do I do that?

Comment: Are your constraints related to the Safe Area ?

Comment: I used the header and footer properties. I just want to extend them to the end of the screen

Answer (score 0):

From `tylerf` (Apple Staff, and possibly [@smileyborg](https://twitter.com/smileyborg)) on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88212#267040):

> If you are using flow layout in your collection view, you can use the
>   section inset to make sure your content in the collection view remains
>   inside the safe area. You can use the new
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInsetReference property (set to
>   .fromSafeArea) so this happens automatically.

However, my content still scrolled past my footer view and into the safe area, like your screenshot showed. Instead, I determined the safe area thusly:

```
self.safeAreaLayoutGuide = [UILayoutGuide new];
[self addLayoutGuide:safeAreaLayoutGuide];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
          [safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor],
          [safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor],
          [safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor],
          [safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor],
          ]];
```

And then, in my `-layoutSubviews`, method, I can inset my `bounds`, with the `safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame`:

```
UIEdgeInsets safeAreaEdgeInsets = 
UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGRectGetMinY(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame),
                 CGRectGetMinX(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame),
                 CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMinY(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame) - CGRectGetHeight(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame),
                 CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMinX(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame) - CGRectGetWidth(safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame));
self.collectionView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, safeAreaEdgeInsets);
```